No funciona el scheduled en el servidor
Cordial saludo a todos tengo un proyecto pequeño en spring boot y lo tengo con una ejecución programada, pero he intentado de todo y no me ejecuta, si yo de forma local creo un contenedor y agrego mi proyecto spring boot al contenedor, me funciona de maravilla pero en el servidor no, actualmente desconosco mi servidor, solo se que es linux.
por mi lado yo tengo esto
@Scheduled(cron = "0 4 14 * * ?")
    public void scheduleFunction() {
        try {
            String token = expiredCardService.Oauth2();
            String expCard = expiredCardService.expiredCard(token);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.err.println("Error al ejecutar la tarea programada: " + e.getMessage());
        }
    }

pero la verdad no se que mas hacer o que debo mirar para que se ejecute, inclusive en el mismo proyecto hice un metodo GET con lo mismo
@GetMapping("/executetask")
    public ResponseEntity<String> executeTask() {
        String token = _expiredCardService.Oauth2();
        String expCard = _expiredCardService.expiredCard(token);
        return ResponseEntity.ok(expCard);
    }

y en el postman si se me ejecuta sin problema alguno, lo que logre identificar solamente es que la tarea programada no se esta ejecutando, en el lado del servidor no se absolutamente nada, debido a que infraestructura no da razon absoluta de nada, simplemente dice es el código y ya
el proyecto es un spring boot version 3.4.0
aca les dejo mi pom.xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>3.4.0-M2</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>ExpiredCards.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>ExpiredCards</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>ExpiredCards</name>
    <description>Expired Cards</description>
    <url/>
    <licenses>
        <license/>
    </licenses>
    <developers>
        <developer/>
    </developers>
    <scm>
        <connection/>
        <developerConnection/>
        <tag/>
        <url/>
    </scm>
    <properties>
        <java.version>22</java.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
            <version>2.15.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
            <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>spring-milestones</id>
            <name>Spring Milestones</name>
            <url>https://repo.spring.io/milestone</url>
            <snapshots>
                <enabled>false</enabled>
            </snapshots>
        </repository>
    </repositories>
    <pluginRepositories>
        <pluginRepository>
            <id>spring-milestones</id>
            <name>Spring Milestones</name>
            <url>https://repo.spring.io/milestone</url>
            <snapshots>
                <enabled>false</enabled>
            </snapshots>
        </pluginRepository>
    </pluginRepositories>

</project>

